# Why are domain sizes of all lengths when the correlation length is infinite at $T_c$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

Given that the correlation length diverges at the critical point, why are domains of finite size?

What is the relationship for a ferromagnet between correlation length and domain size?

Comment: Keep in mind divergent phenomena come from taking the thermodynamic limit of infinite system size. Or are you asking something different?

Answer (score 5):

You can microscopically describe the correlation between fluctuations with a correlation function $G(r)$.
This function usually depends on $r$ through both a power law and an exponential, i.e.
$$G(r) \propto r^{-\tau} \, e^{-r/\xi} \,,$$
where $\tau$ is a scaling exponent and $\xi$ is the correlation length.
Intuitively, at the critical point, $\xi$ diverges and the exponential goes to one. Therefore, $G(r)$ becomes a pure power law at the critical point
$$G(r) \to r^{-\tau} \,.$$
Power laws are scale invariant, which means that $G(r)$ (and therefore the correlations in your material) look the same on every lengthscale, leading to correlated domains of every size.

For a more rigorous discussion, check out any book on critical phenomena. I can recommend 'Elements of Phase Transitions and Critical Phenomena' by Hidetoshi Nishimori and Gerardo Ortiz.

Answer (score 1):

The *expected* size of the cluster containing a specific point is infinite at the critical point. Possibly the simplest way of seeing that is through the representation in terms of **F[K percolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_cluster_model)**.

The latter is defined as follows (oversimplifying a bit). Given a finite box $\Lambda_L=\{-L,\dots,L\}^d\subset\mathbb{Z}^d$, configurations of the model are given by collections $\mathbf{n}=(n_{e})_{e\in\mathcal{E}_L}$, where $\mathcal{E}_L$ denotes the set of nearest-neighbor edges in $\Lambda_L$, and $n_{e}\in\{0,1\}$ for all $e\in\mathcal{E}_L$. The interpretation of $\mathbf{n}$ is as follows: $\mathbf{n}$ corresponds to the subgraph of $\Lambda_L$ in which an edge $e\in\mathcal{E}_L$ is present if and only if $n_e=1$. The probability of $\mathbf{n}$ is given by
$$
\mathbb{P}_{L,p}(\mathbf{n}) = \frac{1}{Z_{L,p}} \, 2^{\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{n})} \prod_{e:\,n_e=1} p \prod_{e:\,n_e=0} (1-p) ,
$$
where $p\in [0,1]$ is a parameter of the model, $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{n})$ denotes the number of connected components (*clusters*) in $\mathbf{n}$, and $Z_{L,p}$ is a normalizing constant (the partition function of the model).

Let us denote by $\{i\leftrightarrow j\}$ the event that vertices $i$ ans $j$ are connected (i.e., belong to the same cluster of $\mathbf{n}$).
It is not difficult to show that the 2-point function of the Ising model in $\Lambda_L$ at inverse temperature $\beta$ can be expressed as
$$
\langle\sigma_i\sigma_j\rangle_{L,\beta} = \mathbb{P}_{L,p_\beta}(i \leftrightarrow j)
$$
provided one chooses $p = p_\beta = 1-e^{-2\beta}$. That is, the 2-point function $\langle\sigma_0\sigma_x\rangle_{L,\beta}$ is equal to the probability that $i$ and $j$ belong to the same FK-percolation cluster.

This immediately implies that the average size of the cluster containing $0$ is given by
$$
\mathbb{E}_{L,p_\beta}\Bigl[ \sum_{i\in\Lambda_L} 1_{\{0\leftrightarrow i\}} \Bigr]
= \sum_{i\in\Lambda_L} \mathbb{P}_{L,p_\beta}(0\leftrightarrow i)
= \sum_{i\in\Lambda_L} \langle\sigma_0\sigma_i\rangle_{L,\beta}.
$$
This remains true in the limit $L\to\infty$. In particular, if $\beta<\beta_{\rm c}$, then $\langle\sigma_0\sigma_i\rangle_{\beta} \asymp e^{-\|i\|/\xi_\beta}$ (again, oversimplifying somewhat), where $\xi_\beta$ is the correlation length, so that
$$
\sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}^d} \langle\sigma_0\sigma_i\rangle_{L,\beta} = \mathsf{O}(\xi_\beta^d).
$$
This shows that the average diameter of a cluster is of the order of the correlation length (when $\beta<\beta_{\rm c}$).

Moreover, as $\lim_{\beta\uparrow\beta_{\rm c}}\xi_\beta=\infty$, we conclude that the average cluster size diverges at the critical point.

---

**Note:** *Stricto sensu*, the above concerns the size of FK-percolation clusters, which do not coincide with "same-spin" cluster in the Ising model. However, FK-percolation clusters are always contained in Ising clusters, so that the above at least provides lower bounds on the expected size of Ising clusters. In particular, this implies the divergence of the average size of Ising clusters at the critical point.